# Network request fails when clicking link during Cypress test and forcing it to remain in the same tab

Tags: cypress

In my Cypress test I need to click a link that redirects and (normally) opens the correct page (which has a different domain) in a new tab. Because Cypress can't manage multiple tabs, I have forced it to open the link in the same tab using:

```
.invoke('removeAttr', 'target').click()
```

However, when doing this the request fails. I can see the failed request in the Network tab of DevTools:

[image]

This does not happen if I allow it to open in the new tab:

[image]

Also, if I get the redirect URL and paste it into the address bar of the first tab, everything works as expected. I have tried to do cy.visit() to the redirect URL instead of clicking the link with .invoke('removeAttr', 'target'), but get the same result.

I have managed to find a nasty work-around to this, but would still like to know if anyone has a better solution - if I save the redirect URL to a file, then in a separate test navigate to the saved url using cy.visit(), it works fine. It just won't let me do it within the same test.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you need to set chromeWebSecurity off, since you have `strict-origin-when-cross-origin` as Referer Policy.

To do this, go to `cypress.config.js`

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:1234',
    chromeWebSecurity: false,
  },
})
```

Ref [Configuration](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/configuration#Browser)

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately this didn't work for my particular issue.